# Python script to delete duplicates in csv file taking too long to run. How could I optimize it?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with two columns and 500k rows. I loaded into `table_dupes` and wrote the following `for` loop to delete duplicate rows (based on the whole row).

Even though this works fine for smaller files, for this particular case it has been running for over 30 minutes.

How could I optimize it?

```
unique_rows = []
table_no_dupes = []

for row in table_dupes:
    if row not in unique_rows:
        unique_rows.append(row)
        table_no_dupes.append(row)
```

Comment: You should try pandas or NumPy. these are writtenn in CPP for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a for loop, especially for long files is very inafficient. You can use import pandas and do the following.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

css_file.to_csv(file_path_where_you_want_it_to_be)
```

I will include links to documenting information for all the links used if you want further information, but hopefully this can solve your issue!

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html